# How to get HTML data from web page to Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to get data from HTML filtered by the class, for example

`<p class="job_list_first_line">`

In that class I want to grab some data like value of

`<a href="adasdasdasd.html" title="blablabla"> some value text text text < /a >`

tag.

Is that possible?
Please note that I am interested in retrieving that data for web pages that I have no control over.

Thanks everyone in advance,
Wolf.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the whole html page and filter it with help of String methods and regex.
There are so many threads in here for that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe JSoup can help you? This is an HTML parser:

> jsoup implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification, and parses HTML to the same DOM as modern browsers do.

- scrape and parse HTML from a URL, file, or string
- find and extract data, using DOM traversal or CSS selectors
- manipulate the HTML elements, attributes, and text
- clean user-submitted content against a safe white-list, to prevent XSS attacks
- output tidy HTML

[JSoup link](http://jsoup.org/)